# Vectorizing array access from indices matrix

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, matrix-indexing

Consider the following:

```
In [51]: arr = np.arange(6, 10)

In [52]: idx = np.random.randint(4, size=(3, 4))

In [53]: idx
Out[53]:
array([[0, 3, 3, 1],
    [1, 3, 3, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [54]: result = np.empty_like(idx)

In [55]: for i in range(idx.shape[0]):
    ...:     result[i] = arr[idx[i]]
    ...:

In [56]: result
Out[56]:
array([[6, 9, 9, 7],
    [7, 9, 9, 8],
    [7, 7, 7, 7]])
```

How can I vectorize the `for` loop? I couldn't find a way accessing a 1D array "multiple times" via indices matrix where each row is an index array.

Comment: Simply `arr[idx]`, output shape is usually determined by `idx` shape

Comment: Damn, I can't believe I didn't even tried it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you can simply index into the array `arr` using the `idx` array.

```
In [47]: arr 
Out[47]: array([6, 7, 8, 9])

In [48]: idx     
Out[48]: 
array([[3, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 3, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 2, 3]])

In [49]: arr[idx] 
Out[49]: 
array([[9, 8, 8, 6],
       [6, 9, 8, 9],
       [9, 8, 8, 9]])
```

---

If you want an approach that is less magical and more enlightening, then the below one would be more helpful.

```
# flatten the `idx` array; index into `arr`; then reshape to `idx's` shape.

In [50]: arr[idx.ravel()].reshape(idx.shape) 
Out[50]: 
array([[9, 8, 8, 6],
       [6, 9, 8, 9],
       [9, 8, 8, 9]])
```